# iOS App Store: How To Hold For Release after binary upload?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Hey I've already submitted an updated app binary to the apple store. Originally I selected "release as soon as it's approved". I want to change that to "Hold for developer release". Any idea how to change it? I've been snooping around itunesconnect but nothing as popped up.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. You only get one chance to make that selection for each update. You'd have to reject your binary and resubmit and make the proper selection.

Sorry this isn't the answer you're looking for.

Comment: That's the right answer. If you need to change that you have to reject the binary and resubmit waiting a long week again.

Comment: I generally always select hold for developer release because it takes only a second to release it myself but gives me the flexibility to hold it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't without rejecting the binary and uploading it again; but if you want to, you can go to **rights and pricing** and move the availability date to a later date. Users won't be able to download you app during that time, but neither the update will be available to existing users when the new version gets approved.